# How to build a DFA for the given language and prove its correctness?

Tags: automata, regular-language

Let's say $L$ is a regular language.
(reminder: the word $x$ is a $\text{Prefix}$ of the word $w$ if: $w=xy$, for some $y$ $\in$ $\Sigma^*$)

$L_{pref} = \{w | \text{ at most  $1$ prefix of $w$ is not in } L\}$

I need to build a DFA for $L_{pref}$ and prove its correctness.

I tried everything :(
Any ideas?

Comment: Don’t you mean that $x$ is a prefix of $w$ if $w=xy$ for some $y\in\Sigma^{\color{red}*}$? (There is a basic tutorial and reference [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to write mathematical expression on this site.)

Comment: thanks for the tutorial! i just edit :)

Comment: Hint: let's say we're given a DFA for $L$.  Then, can you come up with an algorithm for taking a string and determining whether it's in $L_{pref}$?  If so, and your algorithm only examines each element of the string in sequence once, and your algorithm only needs to maintain a finite amount of state, then you'll essentially have your answer.

Comment: @ryden: You’re welcome, and thanks for editing it. If you have DFAs $M_1$ and $M_2$ with the same input alphabet $\Sigma$, do you know how to combine them to make a single DFA that accepts a word $w\in\Sigma^*$ if and only if $M_1$ and $M_2$ **both** accept $w$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:
will that be the DFA $M_1 \cap M_2$ ?

Comment: @ryden: Yes, if that’s your notation for the DFA that accepts the intersection of the languages accepted by $M_1$ and $M_2$. But never mind that: I thought that I could use that to simplify the answer considerably, but I was mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Let $M$ be a DFA for $L$, and add a new state $q^*$ that is not in $M$. If $\epsilon\notin L$, every word over $\Sigma$ already has a prefix not in $L$, so one more ‘bad’ prefix takes it out of $L_{\text{pref}}$. Modify $M$ as follows: if $q\overset{a}\longrightarrow q'$ is a transition of $M$ such that $q'$ is not an acceptor state, replace it with $q\overset{a}\longrightarrow q^*$, and let $q^*$ be a non-acceptor state with transitions $q\overset{a}\longrightarrow q^*$ for every $a\in\Sigma$. The resulting DFA will accept $w\in\Sigma^*$ if and only if $\epsilon$ is the only prefix of $w$ that is not in $L$.

If $\epsilon$ **is** in $L$, a word $w\in\Sigma$ has to drive $M$ to non-acceptor states twice in order to be rejected. See if you can design a suitable DFA by adding to $M$ not just the ‘garbage’ state $q^*$ but also a whole second copy $M'$ of $M$. The idea is that the machine should stay in the original $M$ as long as the input keeps it in acceptor states but switch to $M'$ when the input sends it to a non-acceptor state.

Comment: In case $\epsilon \notin L$, can i say that a word $w \in L_{pref}$ if and only if $w \in L$?

Comment: @ryden: No, because $w$ could still have a prefix that isn’t in $L$. Suppose, for instance, that $L$ is the set of all $w\in\{a\}^*$ such that $|w|$ is odd. Then $\epsilon\notin L$, and $aaa\in L$, but $aaa\notin L_{\text{pref}}$, because its prefix $aa$ is not in $L$.