# Constructing a DFA for a language

Tags: automata, regular-language

Yesterday I saw there was a discussion of the following problem, which I'm interested in too:

Given that L is a regular language, construct a DFA for L-pref, where L-pref is defined as follows:

L-pref = {w | at most one prefix of w is not in L}

I've read the solution suggested here,

[How to build a DFA for the given language and prove its correctness?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4081911/how-to-build-a-dfa-for-the-given-language-and-prove-its-correctness)

but I don't understand the solution entirely. I understand the case where epsilon belongs to L, but I don't understand the solution in the case in which epsilon doesn't belong to L (i.e the two machine copies thing).

I'd be glad if you could explain how to transition between the two copies, preferably referring to an example of an accepting run of a word and a non-accepting run of some other word.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use the same notation as in that answer.

Any transition in $M$ that goes to a non-acceptor state should be changed to go to the corresponding state in $M'$. That means that when $M$ first finds a prefix that is not in $L$, the automaton shifts over to $M'$. Similarly, any transition in $M'$ that goes to a non-acceptor state is changed to go to the ‘garbage’ state $q^*$; this ensures that a second prefix not in $L$ sends the automaton to $q^*$, where it remains forever in a non-acceptor state.

Remember that $M'$ starts out as an exact copy of $M$, except that we don’t care which state is $M$’s initial state. Thus, an input word in $L_{\text{pref}}$ affects the new automaton almost exactly as it affects $M$: the only difference is that if it has one non-$L$ prefix, the new automaton jumps over to $M'$ when that is found and continues its route in that copy of $M$ instead of in $M$ itself. And the adjustments to $M_1$ ensure that a second non-$L$ prefix will dump the new automaton into the ‘garbage’ state.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I truly appreciate it.
So if I had L = {d, do, dom, domin, epsilon}, then 'domino' does not belongs to L-pref and 'domin' does belong to L-pref. When reading 'domino', when we reach the letter 'i', we will switch to a non-acceptor in the copy, and when reading n, we will reach an acceptor state in  the copy, and finally when reading 'o' we will go to q* and remain their forever.
When reading 'domin' though, when reading 'i' we will move to a non-acceptor in the copy, but when reading 'n' we go to an acceptor in the copy, so 'domin' gets accepted.
Am I right?
Thanks!!!

Comment: @sovlani: Yes, that’s what would happen. You’re welcome!

Comment: Thank you! You have no idea how much you helped me and how much it means to me.
All the best :)

Comment: @sovlani: You’re most welcome!